# localStorage loop missing records after deleting 2 records ( on a different page )

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Everything seems to work fine when I add records using my form. They all show up nicely on the page.
When I press on the delete button that is generated with each record, it removes the record and reloads the page. This also works. The second time I do this though, my records seem to vanish.

For example, I add 5 records titled : a,b,c,d,e. They show up, I delete record b, the list reloads with a,c,d,e without a problem. The moment I delete c from the newly generated list my e record vanishes, so it shows only a and d.

Clearly I am doing something horribly wrong, I am hoping someone can show me what that is. If it's bad programming practice this way, please let me know in what direction to search for the right way.

I have 3 seperate pages:

Storing records:

```
function storeEntry(){
    var myId = localStorage.length;
    addBtn.addEventListener("touchstart", submitEntry, false);
    addBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", submitEntry, false);

    function submitEntry(event) {
        //Get the form data to store in the Array
        var myTitle = document.getElementById("myTitle").value;
        var myDate = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
        var myContent = document.getElementById("myContent").value;
        //Fill array that will be placed in localstorage
        var myArray = [myId,myTitle,myDate,myContent];
        //Store it as a json string
        localStorage.setItem(myId, JSON.stringify(myArray));
        //Provide feedback
        alert("Item: " + myTitle + " has been added with id: "+myId);
        //Id +1 zodat het volgende item een uniek id krijgt.
        myId=myId+1;
        //Clear the form
        setFields();
    }
}
```

For deleting records:

```
function deleteEntry(){
    var key=localStorage.key(this.i);
    this.removeEventListener("click",deleteEntry);
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    alert("Item : "+key+" is verwijderd!");
    window.location.href = "showEntry.html";
}
```

And finally for showing records:

```
function loadEntries(){
    var myEntryBox = document.getElementById("entryBox");
    var myvar="";
    for(var i=0;i<=localStorage.length;i++){
        if(localStorage.getItem(i)!==null) {

            var myData = JSON.parse(localStorage[i]);
            myvar = myvar +"-------------------"+ myData;
            var newNode = document.createElement('div');
            newNode.innerHTML = myData;
            myEntryBox.appendChild( newNode );

            var delButton = document.createElement('button');
            delButton.innerHTML = "Del";
            delButton.i=myData[0];
            newNode.appendChild(delButton);
            alert("This node id is: "+myData[0]);
            delButton.addEventListener("click",deleteEntry);

        }
        else{
            alert("Geen data");
        }

        document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = myvar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies with your key id... You are setting it to the localstorage length, but when you remove an item the length is changed... Try using a counter instead and increment by ++.

I think your looking at it like an array, but its really an object ( like a dictionary) with a length property... you're removing the keys so the length is "wrong"..

```
var counter = 0;

function storeEntry(){
    counter++;
    var myId = counter;
    addBtn.addEventListener("touchstart", submitEntry, false);
    addBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", submitEntry, false);

    function submitEntry(event) {
        ...
        //Id +1 zodat het volgende item een uniek id krijgt.
        //myId=myId+1; <-- no need anymore
    }
}
```

You will need to fix your delete ....

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my problem,

On the showEntry page I was looping with:

```
for(var i=0;i<=localStorage.length;i++){
    if(localStorage.getItem(i)!==null) {

        var myData = JSON.parse(localStorage[i]);
```

I have changed this to :

```
for(var i=0;i<=localStorage.length;i++){
    var myKey=localStorage.key(i);
    if(localStorage.getItem(myKey)!==null) {
```

localStorage.getItem was trying to find items matching some key from the i variable, but that would result in errors since the key names stored can be way higher than the length of localstorage after deleting items.